# How to use two functions with the same name but different namespaces?

Tags: c++, linux, function, namespaces

I have the following problem in my codeexample, wirtten for Linux:

example.h

```
namespace abc
{
   int open();
}
```

example.cc

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include "example.h"
int abc::open()
{
   int a = open("abc", 123);
}
```

I intended to use open("abc", 123) in context with ioctl.h but the function is used as defined in my namespace abc.

How can write the programm to use the right open() function?

Thanks for your help.

Tobias

Comment: Use `::open(....)` Since the two function have a different signature, the compiler might be able to deduce it itself. Or do you get an error?

Comment: Cheers, this solved my problem!